# Modifying attributes of a Moose::Role at runtime

Tags: perl, moose, mop

I have a Moose::Role that contains a network client as an attribute:

```
package Widget;
use Moose::Role;

has 'network_thingy' => (
    isa => Maybe[ThingyClient],
);
```

And of course, I have a couple concrete Moose classes which use this role:

```
package BlueWidget;
use Moose;
with 'Widget';
```

Now it comes to functional testing of the Widgets.  We have the ability to create `ThingyServer` objects, and it would be much faster and overall excellent to directly use ThingyServer objects instead of spinning up a daemon and having a ThingyClient connect to it over the network.  Since ThingyClient & ThingyServer conveniently have the exact same methods, this should be easily possible.  But of course, Moose is demanding that I use a ThingyClient when the test eventually constructs a BlueWidget.

I did some research, and came across the Moose::Meta documentation.  Seemed perfect!  So here's the test code:

```
my $metarole = Moose::Meta::Role->initialize('Widget');

// first remove the old attribute
$metarole->remove_attribute('network_thingy');
```

I was going to add a new attribute, but I thought I'd check on the state of the role & class first.   Now if I dump out the $metarole, it looks great.  There's no network_thingy attribute anymore.  But if I construct a BlueWidget class, or just peak inside the metaclass...

```
$metaclass = Moose::Meta::Class->initialize('BlueWidget');
diag Dumper ($metaclass);
```

... sure enough `network_thingy` is still there.  This is not at all what I expected.  How can I modify/remove/replace an attribute of the Widget role at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

When a class consumes a role, attributes are *copied* from the role to the class. If you then change the attribute in the role, the *copy* in the class is unaffected.

So you would need to loop through the classes that have consumed the role, and change the attribute in each class. There's a `consumers` method in Moose::Meta::Role that could help you get a list of classes that have consumed the role, however it only covers classes that have *directly* consumed the role, and not, say, subclasses of those.

If the classes have been made immutable (`__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable`), you'll need to make them mutable again before you make modify the attribute.

Overall, it's probably a better idea to just alter the role module (i.e. edit the file); not attempt to tweak the attribute at run time. Maybe set `isa` to a duck_type type constraint?